# SELECT same element from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I got these two tables:

```
Create table  Consumidor  (
    numero  int(9),
    email   varchar(30) not null,
    sexo    char(1) not null,
    nascimento  date    not null,
    constraint Consumidor_sexo_RI001     check (sexo in ('F','M')),
    constraint Consumidor_unique_RI002  unique(email),
    constraint pk_Consumidor     primary key (numero)
);

Create table  Dependente  (
    consumidor  int(9),
    numero  int(2),
    sexo    char(1) not null,
    nascimento  date    not null,
    constraint Dependente_sexo_RI003 check (sexo in ('F','M')),
    constraint fk_Dependente_consumidor  foreign key (consumidor) references Consumidor(numero) on delete cascade,
    constraint pk_Dependente     primary key (consumidor,numero)
);
```

What I wanna do is SELECT the 'sexo' and 'nascimento' of both tables. I don't understand how I can do this.

------------------ EDIT -----------------------
The result table should look something like this:

```
idade | sexo
  34  |  F
```

It only has two columns for both tables.

Comment: inner join ? left join ? ...?

Comment: FYI, `CHECK` constraints are ignored by MySQL.

Comment: Why do you have the same field in both tables? This seems like a normalization failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Query**:

```
SELECT c.sexo as "Consumidor", c.nascimento as "Consumidor",
       d.sexo as "Dependente", d.nascimento as "Dependente"
FROM
      Consumidor c JOIN Dependente d ON c.numero = d.consumidor
ORDER BY
      c.nascimento;
```

**Result**:

```
Consumidor  Consumidor  Dependente  Dependente
    M       2012-08-06       F      2012-08-06
```

If you want to combine them together perhaps

```
SELECT group_concat(c.sexo,"|",d.sexo) as "sexo", 
       group_concat(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,c.nascimento,CURDATE())
                    ,"|"
                    ,TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,d.nascimento,CURDATE())) as "idade"
FROM
      Consumidor c JOIN Dependente d ON c.numero = d.consumidor
ORDER BY
      c.nascimento;
```

Which produces:

```
sexo    idade
F|M      5|5
```

Comment: What you did was my first attempt, but I want something different , sorry.
I edited my question. I want a SELECT table with only two columns - 'idade' and 'sexo'